# ArrayFormula + SumIf ( Header + ROW Criteria)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm in need of an Arrayformula that can SUM all the numbers of a ROW with the HEADER (this) as the condition, been searching all day, how can I do this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2p85.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=ArrayFormula(MMULT(filter(A2:H, len(H2:H)) , transpose(--regexmatch(A1:H1, "this"))))one way would be to get the columns in a literal array and use MMULT

```
=ArrayFormula(MMULT({A2:A10, C2:C10, E2:E10, G2:G10}, {1;2;3;4}^0))
```

where col A, C, E, G are the columns to be summed (per row).

or for a more automated way:

```
=ArrayFormula(MMULT(filter(A2:H, len(H2:H)) , transpose(--regexmatch(A1:H1, "this"))))
```

where A1:H10 is the range with data (row 1 = headerrow).

[example sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wZ_Ytj4ILTrj7qDe7SEkjBc96VVKVMACB4u8zNpCdxU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Had to make a custom function to handle text but everything worked perfectly, thanks!